# How can I merge my Careers2.0 and StackOverflow email address?

Tags: support, jobs

I updated my Stackoverflow login by creating a new stackexchange account using a certain email. Now I want to use the same email for Careers2.0 but I cannot do that. When I tried to edit the email address in Careers2.0, it gives me error saying "Already Registered". Of course it is but on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That message means you already have an account on **Careers** with that same email address. I found your accounts and have merged them, so you should be all set.

Comment: Thank you. It looks good now.